# Check the checkbox when data already present

Tags: angular10

Data is coming from the backend and there are some conditions if the condition returns true then the checkbox should be checked otherwise uncheck

My code:

HTML

```
<div class="form-check"
                *ngFor="let cat of categories">
                <input class="form-check-input"
                  (change)="onChange(cat.name, $event.target.checked)"
                  name="{{ cat.name }}"
                  type="checkbox"
                  [attr.checked]="checkBank(cat.id)"
                  [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
                  id="{{cat.id}}">
                <label class="form-check-label"
                  for="{{cat.name}}">
                  {{cat.name}}
                </label>
              </div>
```

TS code

```
 async checkProduct(product) {
    let response = await this.dataService.getEligibleBanksForProduct(
      product.id
    );
    this.eligibleBanksList = response['lenderList'];
  }
  async checkBank(companyId) {
    if (
      companyId &&
      this.eligibleBanksList &&
      this.eligibleBanksList.length > 0
    ) {
      this.eligibleBanksList.map((element) => {
        console.log('ELementID=>', element.lenderid);
        if (element.lenderid == companyId) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      });
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Please help I'm doing this for 2 days

Answer (score 0):

use checked property

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="true">
```